# dang expected declaration got me held up (probably simple to solve) but I'm rusty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

so I got a problem. I am trying to put a UIButton on a TableViewController and another kind fellow told me how to do it, and now I am getting the error expected declaration. I am suspecting that it has to do with it not being part of a function, but when I put it in the ViewDidLoad(), it gives me another error. Here are the pictures titled of the errors:
This is when the function navButtonPressed and self.navigationItem is outside the ViewDidLoad()
[image]
This is when the function navButtonPressed and self.navigationItem is inside the ViewDidLoad()
[image]

Thanks for any help, and I know this is probably a simple mistake.

Comment: Please post error log and code in here, not image

Comment: And post the relevant code that explains what's going on.

Comment: Tj3n its now giving me an error on the function, which says "consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by a ;"

Comment: can anyone help me with this: http://imgur.com/a/XC2xY

Comment: @user7424546 Why do you have to have your func inside viewDidLoad? This would be so much easier (see my answer) if you don't do it that way

Comment: Benjamin Lowry here it is when it is not in the viewdidload: http://imgur.com/a/3DuLf

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the func out of viewDidLoad()

So you would have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //initialize button with target "myButtonPressed"
}

func myButtonPressed() {
    //do something
}
```

From what I can gather from your code, there is no reason why you could need the func inside viewDidLoad.